# Consequences of hard (unclean) shutdown of a Linux system

Tags: linux, shutdown

I have Lubuntu on my 7 year old PC with 512 MB RAM and and Intel Dual Pentium Processor running at 3.00 GHz. I sometimes unplug it from the electrical mains in an emergency. Please tell me if something bad will happen if I do this.

Comment: Please learn how to use the Caps_Lock key properly, rather than indiscriminately SHOUT your question title and then fail to use it at all in the question body. Voting to close on the principle that if you are too lazy to care about your question, I can't be bothered answering.

Comment: It is not so bad, as it seems, it causes only rarely problems, but these problems require a linux skill on Linux, and they are nearly unfixable on Win.

Answer (score 8):

### TL;DR

Don't do this. You'll eventually corrupt something.

### Risks

Unclean shutdowns have all sorts of risks. Some of these risks include:

1. Corrupting the filesystem.
2. Ending up with dirty data in your files even if your metadata is okay.
3. Problems with any applications that require a clean shutdown such as databases, network file systems, and so forth.

### Magic SysRq as an Alternative

You'd be much better off with the sequence:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>

to sync the disks, remount them read-only, and reboot.

Comment: perfect answer!!!!! +1

Comment: what happens when we sync the disks, remount them read-only, and reboot? do we repair something? or anything else?

Comment: @Utkarsh You flush all data to disk and unmount the disks safely. However, applications still won't have an opportunity to respond to any signals sent at normal shutdown; you can try `Alt+SysRq+e` before unmounting if you think some processes will listen, but it may be safer to block further filesystem access altogether. YMMV. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key for additional options.

Comment: This is an urban legend perpetuated without actually experiencing any issues. If you are asking for trouble and pulling power cord during heavy disk activity, you may sometimes end up with inconsistent state. But this is strongly alleviated by transactional FSs and DBs and chances are very low. If they wait for disk IO to subside, and then power cycle, there is very little chance of problems. I power cycled Linux machines for decades, including for testing specifically that, and did not any FS issues, not even once. On MS Windows it's a different story - doing so was catastrophic very often.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you boot after doing this you will notice that your partitions are flagged dirty and have to be checked before the boot can continue. Eventually you'll pull the plug during a write and lose whatever data you were writing. Eventually you'll get unrecoverable disk errors. Eventually you'll have to reformat the filesystems and start over. How long is "eventually?" No one can say for sure but you get a day closer every time you pull that plug.

Comment: How many FS failures have you observed by doing so? Just for statistics, please.